Expects Inputs Error when loading working model
I've trained a CNN using a pre trained model (EfficientNetB0) and refining it with my data.
(Don't get confused, I did it using a TPU VM, same error everything when not using it)
This is how I did it:
`with strategy.scope():
    base_model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet')
    base_model.trainable = False

    model = Sequential([
        base_model,
        GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.5),
        Dense(2, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

steps_per_epoch = len(train_data) // 32
validation_steps = len(val_data) // 32

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    validation_steps=validation_steps,
    epochs=1
)` 

Now whats interesting is, that the model has a very high accuracy using val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(val_dataset, steps=validation_steps) 
Using the model in the same notebook works!
predictions = model.predict(prepared_image)
predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

Now the critical part that does not work:
model.save('/kaggle/working/my_model.keras')

Technically, even this works but when loading the model:
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

I instantly get this error:
ValueError: Layer "dense" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs 
received: [<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1280), dtype=float32, sparse=False, 
name=keras_tensor_504>, <KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1280), dtype=float32, 
sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_505>]

Just loading the model, nothing else. Yes, the paths are all right using the model upload of kaggle and then copying the path.
How can I not load the model, even though I can use it in my notebook where I trained it to predict.

Hi Roert ,The error shows that the Dense layer is receiving  two input tensors instead of one.check that you are using GlobalAveragePooling2Dcorrectly try to reduce the dimensionality of the input from (7, 7, 1280) to (1280) (for EfficientNetB0).Make sure that there are no extra input being passed while reloading.
